# recvfrom in socket programming with C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, recvfrom

So I was trying to understand socket programming in C when I came across this code:

```
/* Sample UDP client */

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int sockfd,n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char sendline[] = "Hello UDP server! This is UDP client";
    char recvline[1000];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage:  ./%s <IP address>\n",argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);

    sendto(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline),0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    n=recvfrom(sockfd,recvline,10000,0,NULL,NULL);
    recvline[n]=0;
    printf("Received: %s\n",recvline);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the `recvfrom()` call does not need an ip address to send the message. A look at the man pages revealed the following lines:

> If src_addr is not NULL, and the underlying protocol provides the
>   source address, this source address is filled  in. When  src_addr  is
>   NULL,  nothing  is  filled  in;  in this case, addrlen is not used,
>   and should also be NULL.

So I think that the underlying protocol provides the source IP address. My problem is, how does it really figure out the address to receive the message from ? Is it that, once you send a message to an address, you cannot use the same socket to send messages to other addresses ? So that it keeps on using the same address ?

Please help. Couldn't find an answer anywhere in Google or any lecture note.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `recvfrom()` doesn't send. It receives, just as the name suggests. "how does it really figure out the address" --- the sending host sends its address inside the message. The protocol implementation extracts it and gives it back to the program. "once you send a message to an address, you cannot use the same socket to send messages to other addresses" --- that depends on the protocol.

Comment: @n.m. sorry I made a mistake. Should have been 'receive from' not 'send to'. But how does the program know from whom we're expecting our message from ? Many servers from many IPs and ports might be sending messages at the same time ?

Comment: The program doesn't know that beforehand. It's told which message arrives from where. The address parameter is an *out* parameter, it is filled by the system.

Comment: Note, this has a bad memory smasher: `recvline` is declared as being 1000 in size, but you are passing 10000 to `recvfrom` (so 10 * 1000).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misconception that `recvfrom` pulls data from a particular source address.

`recvfrom` is generally used for connectionless protocols like UDP. When an UDP packet is received, it could be from any source address. `src_addr` returns this address for the application usage.

If you are expecting messages only from a particular address, there are 2 ways. (1) Either you can ignore the packets received from other addresses by comparing the address returned in `src_addr`, or (2) use `connect` to specify a particular remote address from where you are expecting messages and the lower socket layer takes care of ignoring packets from other sources. After connect, you could also use `recv` instead of `recvfrom`.

Sending messages are done through `sendto`. You seem to be confusing the 2 calls. Using `sendto` it is possible to send messages to difference addresses on the same socket.